# Не запускается Tomcat 9 в Eclipse

Tags: java, java-ee

После установки сервера Tomcat 9 он не запускается на Eclipse, выдает ошибку

> "The server cannot be started because one or more of the ports are
>   invalid. Open the server editor and correct the invalid ports."

В гугле написано, что надо поменять какие-то порты администратора, что это и где менять?

Comment: После установки сервера, вы его службу остановили? Иначе, у вас запущен один сервер в операционной системе, и второй вы пытаетесь запустить в ide. И оба они хотят один порт

Answer (score 0):

Конфликт был из-за того, что паралельно был запущен еще и сервер от Windows. Его необходимо было отключить. Я же по-незнанию пытался менять порт.